# Where can I find science fiction novels originally written in Esperanto?

Tags: literature

I know Esperanto has been used in science fiction like Red Dwarf, but I'd like to read sf novels or short stories written in Esperanto. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 3):

*[Sferoj](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sferoj)* 1-10 is a classical series of small books with SF stories (a couple of example stories have ”leaked” [online](http://esperanto.net/literaturo/novel/novlibr/sfer.html)).

A number of *Sferoj* can be ordered through UEA’s [bookstore](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?titolo=sferoj&auxtoro=&katego=&kondicho=chio&trovu=Trovu%20en%20la%20reta%20katalogo). Wish I had them all! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could browse through the lists of original [novels](http://esperanto.net/literaturo/roman/index.html) and [short(er) stories](http://esperanto.net/literaturo/novel/index.html) here, looking for "scienc".